# How to handle special characters like "\n" in string reverse?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I have the following code to reverse a string, and I am considering to make test cases for it. I would like to know how to handle cases like when user input "\n", "\t" ?

```
private static String reverse2(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
        return str;

    int start = 0;
    int end = str.length() - 1;

    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    while (start < end) {
        char tmp = chars[start];
        chars[start] = chars[end];
        chars[end] = tmp;

        start++;
        end--;
    }

    return String.valueOf(chars);
}
```

Comment: StringBuilder has a method reverse() ! just use that

Comment: What's wrong with `\n` or `\t` in trying to reverse a string? (They get treated as single characters, so they won't end up as `n\` if that's your concern)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In strings like "\nxyz", str.toCharArray() treats "\n" as a single character. There is no issue in your code. Only thing place of new line char will change and it will print in different line format this time.

Answer (score 4):

```
 StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("Java");

    // reverse characters of the StringBuilder and prints it

    System.out.println("reverse = " + str.reverse());
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not reverse it using a StringBuilder:

```
string input = "xyz\t\nabc123";
string reversed = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is ambiguous and the answer not so simple.

If what you call *user input* is a Java literal string like `"newline -\n-"`, the sequence `\n` is turned into a single newline character. When you print the string, you don't see the `\n` anymore. Instead, further output goes to the next line, giving

```
newline -
-
```

(11 characters). Reversal gives

```
-
- enilwen
```

On the opposite, if *user input* is from the keyboard, the escapes will not be recognized and a print will output the string unchanged.

```
newline -\n-
```

(12 characters). Reversal gives

```
-n\- enilwen
```

If you want the escapes to be recognized and translated, you need to do that yourself by checking every input character.

In the weirdest of the cases, you can restore the escapes after reversal (so that they become visible again), giving the transforms

```
newline -\n-
```

(12 characters) then internally,

```
newline -
-
```

(11 characters) then internally reversed,

```
-
- enilwen
```

(11 characters) then externally

```
-\n- enilwen
```

(12 characters). Notice the difference with above `n\` vs `\n`.